# Does git merge account for commit timestamps?

Tags: git

Here is graph for 2 branches master and sprint1. When the 2 branches are merged I expected "second commit" (Wed Oct 19 19:58:15 2016 -0400) to be after "sprint 1 first commit" (Wed Oct 19 19:57:13 2016 -0400) as that's the time next to "sprint 1 first commit" commit time.

Question: How does the merge happen? Does the timestamp being considered affect it at all?

```
ds-MacBook-Pro:Test1 aks$ git log  --graph
*   commit 48bbcabf5d50e080c82e71ce8661571f061a35c2
|\  Merge: b59ca50 e1195c7
| | Author: hmanan <test@gmail.com>
| | Date:   Wed Oct 19 19:59:53 2016 -0400
| | 
| |     merge commit
| |   
| * commit e1195c7230fd50b3831b3c1ab597bb691c593550
| | Author: hmanan <test@gmail.com>
| | Date:   Wed Oct 19 19:58:15 2016 -0400
| | 
| |     second commit
| |   
* | commit b59ca508357f151520ce7c88c5cc439992bc477c
| | Author: hmanan <test@gmail.com>
| | Date:   Wed Oct 19 19:59:22 2016 -0400
| | 
| |     sprint 1 third commit
| |   
* | commit 68064f65d2570b8f0c22273b431444610c49d97d
|/  Author: hmanan <test@gmail.com>
|   Date:   Wed Oct 19 19:58:56 2016 -0400
|   
|       sprint 1 second commit
|  
* commit f9b26255345373f2cb63d26845d2c651527e13ac
| Author: hmanan <test@gmail.com>
| Date:   Wed Oct 19 19:57:13 2016 -0400
| 
|     Sprint 1 first commit
|  
* commit faa866e8d994f32feed8c1d5e26d4d5eb4197a6f
  Author: hmanan <test@gmail.com>
  Date:   Wed Oct 19 19:55:28 2016 -0400

      first commit
```

Comment: time stamps have nothing to do with git merges. A merge creates a commit that is the successor to two other commits (unless you use --squash). That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@bmargulies mentioned](//stackoverflow.com/questions/40143442/git-merge-between-2-branches#comment67556804_40143442), the timestamps have nothing to do with how the merge is performed. A merge commit merely has pointers to *two* parent commits, rather than one. You can see this in the third line of your output: `Merge: b59ca50 e1195c7`.

To display the commits in "proper" order, use either `--date-order` (for committer date), or `--author-date-order` (for author date).

E.g.:

```
git log --graph --date-order
```